# Duplicate Management - Packaging Matching Rules

Tags: managed-package, validation-rule, duplicate-management

[Matching Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=matching_rules_overview.htm&language=en_US) and [Duplicate Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_overview.htm&language=en_US) are a new feature in Salesforce. I see that matching rules can be pulled as metadata xml, but I can't find any documentation about packaging them.

Can matching rules be bundled in a managed package? Is it a good idea? Can they be considered akin to validation rules? Or should they be considered org level settings? What can be changed by the developer once it's packaged? What can be changed by the end user once it's packaged? Can it be deleted from the package?

Comment: They can be packaged, but they seem to cause an issue when deploying, if a previous version of the rule is active.

Answer (score 1):

Matching Rules seem to behave fine in Managed Packages.  Duplicate Rules, whilst they can be packaged, often cause failed deployments.  They have a 'sort order' attribute which, may or may not conflict with an existing duplicate rule in the subscriber org - and you won't know until deployment if there are other duplicate rules.  Would be great if it were possible to package Duplicate Rules.